# What design pattern to use for a time-measurement profiler service?

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns

I have a symfony2 application. It abstracts a bunch of external APIs, all of them implementing an `ExternalApiInterface`.

Each `ExternalApiInterface` has a lot of methods, e.g. `fetchFoo` and `fetchBar`.

Now, I want to write a service that measures the time of each method call of an instance of an `ExternalApiInterface`.

My current thinking is to implement a `StopWatchExternalApiDecorator`, that wraps each method call. Yet this approach leads, in my understanding, to code duplication.

I think I am going to use the [`StopWatch` component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html) for the time measurement, yet this feels odd:

```
class StopWatchExternalApiDecorator implements ExternalApiInterface {
    public function __construct(ExternalApiInterface $api, Stopwatch $stopWatch)
    {
       $this->api = $api;
       $this->stopWatch = $stopWatch;
    }

    public function fetchBar() {
         $this->stopWatch->start('fetchBar');
         $this->api->fetchBar()
         $this->stopWatch->stop('fetchBar');
    }

    public function fetchFoo() {
         $this->stopWatch->start('fetchFoo');
         $this->api->fetchFoo()
         $this->stopWatch->stop('fetchFoo');
    }
}
```

It seems like I am hurting the DNRY (do not repeat yourself) approach. Am I using the right pattern for this kind of problem, or is there something else more fit? More fit in the sense of: One place to do all the measurement, and no code duplication.

I also dislike of having to touch the decorator in case there will be a new method in the interface. In my mind, that should be independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the decorator approach, just on a different level.

In my architecture, api service was using an `HttpClientInterface`, and each request was handled in the end with a call to `doRequest`. So there, the decorator made most sense without code duplication:

```
<?php
namespace Kopernikus\BookingService\Component\Http\Client;

use Kopernikus\BookingService\Component\Performance\PerformanceEntry;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch;

/**
 * ProfileClientDecorator
 **/
class ProfileClientDecorator implements HttpClientInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Stopwatch
     */
    private $stopwatch;
    /**
     * @var HttpClientInterface
     */
    private $client;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * ProfileClientDecorator constructor.
     * @param HttpClientInterface $client
     * @param Stopwatch           $stopwatch
     * @param LoggerInterface     $logger
     */
    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client, Stopwatch $stopwatch, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->stopwatch = $stopwatch;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function doRequest(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $method =  $request->getMethod();
        $response = $this->doMeasuredRequest($request, $method);
        $performance = $this->getPerformance($method);
        $this->logPerformance($performance);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param string           $method
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    protected function doMeasuredRequest(RequestInterface $request, $method)
    {
        $this->stopwatch->start($method);
        $response = $this->client->doRequest($request);
        $this->stopwatch->stop($method);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * @param $method
     * @return PerformanceEntry
     */
    protected function getPerformance($method)
    {
        $event = $this->stopwatch->getEvent($method);
        $duration = $event->getDuration();

        return new PerformanceEntry($duration, $method);
    }

    /**
     * @param PerformanceEntry $performance
     */
    protected function logPerformance(PerformanceEntry $performance)
    {
        $context = [
            'performance' => [
                'duration_in_ms'       => $performance->getDurationInMs(),
                'request_name' => $performance->getRequestName(),
            ],
        ];

        $this->logger->info(
            "The request {$performance->getRequestName()} took {$performance->getDurationInMs()} ms",
            $context
        );
    }
}
```

And in my `services.yml`:

```
performance_client_decorator:
    class: Kopernikus\Component\Http\Client\ProfileClientDecorator
        decorates: http.guzzle_client
            arguments:
                - @performance_client_decorator.inner
                - @stopwatch
                - @logger
```

Answer (score 0):

i am thinking of some apis i worked on that use one generic function for calls and a method parameter

heres some very basic pseudocode

```
public function call($method = 'fetchBar',$params=array()){
    $this->stopWatch->start($method);
    $this->{"$method"}($params);
    $this->stopWatch->stop($method);

}

private function fetchBar(){
    echo "yo";
}
```

maybe that helps